# Custom Validator Attribute exception in DataAnnotations

Tags: model-view-controller, data-annotations, validation

Has anyone seen this exception before? Google or Bing has absolutely very few results.

```
IsValid(object value) has not been implemented by this class.  
The preferred entry point is GetValidationResult() and classes should override 
IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context).
```

Here's the custom validator:

```
public class PriceAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //I think this definition for IsValid is in DataAnnotations 4.0
            return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            //This I think is the older definition. Not sure why it expects this
            return base.IsValid(value);
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a compiler error or is there a runtime exception being thrown? If so, have you got a stack trace for us?

Comment: @Steven - It's a compiler error. I think it has to do with assembly version of DataAnnotations?

Answer (score 1):

You should actually provide an implementation for one of those methods instead of calling `base.IsValid(value)` or `base.IsValid(value, validationContext)`.

```
public class PriceAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return Id == "120"; // <-- put your condition here
    }
}
```

If the value can be validated without examining other values of the context, you can just override `IsValid(object value)`.