# What should I use instead of DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid as default return in a custom validator?

Tags: asp.net, validation

[Custom Validator Attribute exception in DataAnnotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586708/custom-validator-attribute-exception-in-dataannotations) asks a very similar question.  I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 app I want to add a custom validator.  For the IsValid member I write something like:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
{
    ValidationResult result = null;
    // do some checking, possibly setting result
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = base.IsValid(value, context);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The idea is, I see if the value passes my particular validation rule, and if it does, I return whatever the base says.  In cases my rule passes, the call to base.IsValid throws a NotImplementedException.  I am not sure why.  If I am not supposed to call the base IsValid, should I just return a ValidationResult.Success?

I feel like I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I have seen examples that return both Validationresult.Success and null.

Answer (score 0):

I read the source code for the implementation of ValdidationAttribute.IsValid.  I think the behavior I see is by design.  If I assume that the design intent is to force derived custom validators to implement one of their own IsValids, and I want to throw an exception that contains information to this effect, the base implementation does this.

There is a middling tricky pair of check/try/finally constructs designed to make sure either IsValid(value) or IsValid(value, context) is overridden.  If one of the base IsValids is invoked unflagged, then flag and forward arguments to the other IsValid.  If one of the base IsValids is invoked flagged, then it is because the other base has already been invoked, therefore there is no override, therefore, we didn't do it right, and an exception occurs.

That makes sense to me.  I didn't get this when I started.  Returning ValidationResult.Success is what you *should* return.  You should *never* try to return the base.IsValid.  OK.